# C++ program that creates sin cos and tangent values

Tags: c++

I am new to the C++ language and am trying to create a program that will output all the values for sin, cos, and tangent. The table is suppose to do values 0 to 360 in increments of 10 while using a for loop. I keep getting non stop errors within my for loop and was wondering if someone could show me what I was doing wrong. Any and all suggestions are appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
double x, r;
double sin(x), cos(x), tan(x);
double PI = 3.1415926;

for (x = 0:10:360)
 r= x * PI /180.0;
 cout << "The sin of:" << x << "is:" <<sin(r) << "\n" << endl;
 cout << "The cos of:" << x << "is:" <<cos(r) << "\n" << endl;
 cout << "The tan of:" << x << "is:" <<sin(r)/cos(r) << "\n" << endl;

 return 0;



}
```

Comment: `for (x = 0:10:360)` <-- this right here is not valid C++. You need a good introductory book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `for` loop syntax is wrong and you're missing some braces - try:

```
for (x = 0.0; x < 360.0; x += 10.0)
{
    r = x * PI / 180.0;
    cout << "The sin of: " << x << " is: " << sin(r) << endl;
    cout << "The cos of: " << x << " is: " << cos(r) << endl;
    cout << "The tan of: " << x << " is: " << tan(r) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much all, I really just did not know how to set the condition to the for loop. I made that change and a few others and now i have it working. I really appreciate the help, sorry for asking such a basic question.

Comment: @user3072210 To put it short: Accept the answer then ...